# Javascript to determine if svg text is partially or entirely visible

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working with a svg element which has a line chart and the label at the end of the each line.

A minimum sample is below

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">

    <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="black" stroke="bound" style="overflow: visible;"></rect>
    <rect class="boundRect" x="70" y="70" width="1120" height="600" fill="black"></rect>
    <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(70px, 70px);">

        <g class="lines">
            <path class="Cuba" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,385.8783581344254L46.666666666666664,340.04110795732606L93.33333333333333,340.04110795732606L140,340.04110795732606L186.66666666666666,340.04110795732606L233.33333333333334,340.04110795732606L280,261.5473775717186L326.6666666666667,261.5473775717186L373.3333333333333,261.5473775717186L420,261.5473775717186L466.6666666666667,261.5473775717186L513.3333333333333,193.79191415980043L560,193.79191415980043L606.6666666666666,193.79191415980043L653.3333333333334,174.38265408552468L700,174.38265408552468L746.6666666666666,140.17685505574866L793.3333333333334,140.17685505574866L840,140.17685505574866L886.6666666666666,140.17685505574866L933.3333333333334,140.17685505574866L980,99.07632474477359L1026.6666666666665,99.07632474477359L1073.3333333333335,99.07632474477359L1120,97.28970086328088"></path>
            <path class="Nicaragua" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1
            " d="M0,498.798228969007L46.666666666666664,498.798228969007L93.33333333333333,508.9184060721062L140,508.9184060721062M233.33333333333334,405.6265984654729L280,405.6265984654729L326.6666666666667,405.6265984654729L373.3333333333333,405.6265984654729L420,456.7774936061383L466.6666666666667,426.0869565217393L513.3333333333333,426.0869565217393L560,405.6265984654729L606.6666666666666,405.6265984654729L653.3333333333334,221.48337595907955L700,221.48337595907955L746.6666666666666,221.48337595907955L793.3333333333334,201.02301790281317L840,211.25319693094582L886.6666666666666,170.33248081841413L933.3333333333334,170.33248081841413L980,170.33248081841413L1026.6666666666665,180.56265984654772L1073.3333333333335,155.26826115061547L1120,124.24046541693643"></path>
            <path class="Chad" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,577.4117647058824L46.666666666666664,577.4117647058824L93.33333333333333,577.4117647058824L140,577.4117647058824L186.66666666666666,577.4117647058824M280,545.3510436432637L326.6666666666667,539.2789373814043L373.3333333333333,539.2789373814043L420,539.2789373814043L466.6666666666667,551.4231499051233L513.3333333333333,551.4231499051233L560,551.4231499051233L606.6666666666666,551.4231499051233L653.3333333333334,479.8498122653327L700,459.8247809762202L746.6666666666666,459.8247809762202L793.3333333333334,459.8247809762202L840,459.8247809762202L886.6666666666666,459.8247809762202L933.3333333333334,479.8498122653327L980,456.43070787637083L1026.6666666666665,459.94397759103623L1073.3333333333335,454.75671750181556L1120,296.39468690702114"></path>
            <path class="Rwanda" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,438.6554621848753L46.666666666666664,438.6554621848753L93.33333333333333,438.6554621848753L140,357.98319327731105L186.66666666666666,358.34658187599433L233.33333333333334,358.34658187599433L280,141.17647058823525L326.6666666666667,141.17647058823525L373.3333333333333,141.17647058823525L420,141.17647058823525L466.6666666666667,141.17647058823525L513.3333333333333,70.5882352941176L560,70.5882352941176L606.6666666666666,70.5882352941176L653.3333333333334,70.5882352941176L700,70.5882352941176L746.6666666666666,0L793.3333333333334,0L840,0L886.6666666666666,0L933.3333333333334,23.5294117647058L980,23.5294117647058L1026.6666666666665,23.5294117647058L1073.3333333333335,23.5294117647058L1120,23.5294117647058"></path>
        </g>

        <g class="Label" style="opacity: 1;">
            <text class="labelRwanda" text-anchor="left" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="23.5294117647058" style="overflow: visible;">Rwanda:61.25%</text>
            <text class="labelCuba" text-anchor="left" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="97.28970086328088" style="overflow: visible;">Cuba:53.41%</text>
            <text class="labelNicaragua" text-anchor="left" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="124.24046541693643" style="overflow: visible;">Nicaragua:50.55%</text>
            <text class="labelChad" text-anchor="left" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="296.39468690702114" style="overflow: visible;">Chad:32.26%</text>
        </g>

    </g>

</svg>
```

The entire **text element** for label at the end of line chart is not visible for all of them. For example, for **`class="labelRwanda"`** and **`class="labelNicaragua"`** the entire text elements respectively, **`Rwanda:61.25% and Nicaragua:50.55%`** are not visible. But for other two, **`class="labelCuba" and class="labelChad"`** then entire text elements respectively **`Cuba:53.41% and Chad:32.26%`** are visible.

Is there any way for me to know beforehand, by using `javascript` to know which text elements will be `entirely` visible and which will be `partially` visible.

I tried with `getBBox()` of each of the text elements but they were not of help to me. I initially thought that if `x+width` is greater than `viewbox width than that would be the candidate for` partially visible` elements. But it did not work.

```
document.querySelector('.labelRwanda').getBBox().x+document.querySelector('.labelRwanda').getBBox().width;
document.querySelector('.labelCuba').getBBox().x+document.querySelector('.labelCuba').getBBox().width;
document.querySelector('.labelNicaragua').getBBox().x+document.querySelector('.labelNicaragua').getBBox().width;
document.querySelector('.labelChad').getBBox().x+document.querySelector('.labelChad').getBBox().width;
```

[image: Viz]

**Update**

Based on @Michael Mullany's suggestion, I tried the following where I used `getBoundingClientRect()` instead of `getBBox()` so that I don't need to account for any **transform** coming from the parent element. But I still could not get it to do the job accurately

```css
const parent = document.querySelector('svg').getBoundingClientRect().right;

const ele = document.querySelectorAll('.Label>text');



ele.forEach(
    (a,i)=>{
        const child = a.getBoundingClientRect().right;
        const diff = parent-child;        
        (diff<0)?a.setAttribute('x',`${parseFloat(a.getAttribute('x'))+diff}`):null
        
    }
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">

    <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="black" stroke="bound" style="overflow: visible;"></rect>
    <rect class="boundRect" x="70" y="70" width="1120" height="600" fill="black"></rect>
    <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(70px, 70px);">

        <g class="lines">
            <path class="Cuba" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,385.8783581344254L46.666666666666664,340.04110795732606L93.33333333333333,340.04110795732606L140,340.04110795732606L186.66666666666666,340.04110795732606L233.33333333333334,340.04110795732606L280,261.5473775717186L326.6666666666667,261.5473775717186L373.3333333333333,261.5473775717186L420,261.5473775717186L466.6666666666667,261.5473775717186L513.3333333333333,193.79191415980043L560,193.79191415980043L606.6666666666666,193.79191415980043L653.3333333333334,174.38265408552468L700,174.38265408552468L746.6666666666666,140.17685505574866L793.3333333333334,140.17685505574866L840,140.17685505574866L886.6666666666666,140.17685505574866L933.3333333333334,140.17685505574866L980,99.07632474477359L1026.6666666666665,99.07632474477359L1073.3333333333335,99.07632474477359L1120,97.28970086328088"></path>
            <path class="Nicaragua" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1
            " d="M0,498.798228969007L46.666666666666664,498.798228969007L93.33333333333333,508.9184060721062L140,508.9184060721062M233.33333333333334,405.6265984654729L280,405.6265984654729L326.6666666666667,405.6265984654729L373.3333333333333,405.6265984654729L420,456.7774936061383L466.6666666666667,426.0869565217393L513.3333333333333,426.0869565217393L560,405.6265984654729L606.6666666666666,405.6265984654729L653.3333333333334,221.48337595907955L700,221.48337595907955L746.6666666666666,221.48337595907955L793.3333333333334,201.02301790281317L840,211.25319693094582L886.6666666666666,170.33248081841413L933.3333333333334,170.33248081841413L980,170.33248081841413L1026.6666666666665,180.56265984654772L1073.3333333333335,155.26826115061547L1120,124.24046541693643"></path>
            <path class="Chad" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,577.4117647058824L46.666666666666664,577.4117647058824L93.33333333333333,577.4117647058824L140,577.4117647058824L186.66666666666666,577.4117647058824M280,545.3510436432637L326.6666666666667,539.2789373814043L373.3333333333333,539.2789373814043L420,539.2789373814043L466.6666666666667,551.4231499051233L513.3333333333333,551.4231499051233L560,551.4231499051233L606.6666666666666,551.4231499051233L653.3333333333334,479.8498122653327L700,459.8247809762202L746.6666666666666,459.8247809762202L793.3333333333334,459.8247809762202L840,459.8247809762202L886.6666666666666,459.8247809762202L933.3333333333334,479.8498122653327L980,456.43070787637083L1026.6666666666665,459.94397759103623L1073.3333333333335,454.75671750181556L1120,296.39468690702114"></path>
            <path class="Rwanda" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,438.6554621848753L46.666666666666664,438.6554621848753L93.33333333333333,438.6554621848753L140,357.98319327731105L186.66666666666666,358.34658187599433L233.33333333333334,358.34658187599433L280,141.17647058823525L326.6666666666667,141.17647058823525L373.3333333333333,141.17647058823525L420,141.17647058823525L466.6666666666667,141.17647058823525L513.3333333333333,70.5882352941176L560,70.5882352941176L606.6666666666666,70.5882352941176L653.3333333333334,70.5882352941176L700,70.5882352941176L746.6666666666666,0L793.3333333333334,0L840,0L886.6666666666666,0L933.3333333333334,23.5294117647058L980,23.5294117647058L1026.6666666666665,23.5294117647058L1073.3333333333335,23.5294117647058L1120,23.5294117647058"></path>
        </g>

        <g class="Label" style="opacity: 1;">
            <text class="labelRwanda" id="labelRwanda" text-anchor="left" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="23.5294117647058" style="overflow: visible;">Rwanda:61.25%</text>
            <text class="labelCuba" id="labelCuba" text-anchor="left" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="97.28970086328088" style="overflow: visible;">Cuba:53.41%</text>
            <text class="labelNicaragua" id="labelNicaragua" text-anchor="left" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="124.24046541693643" style="overflow: visible;">Nicaragua:50.55%</text>
            <text class="labelChad" id="labelChad" text-anchor="left" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="296.39468690702114" style="overflow: visible;">Chad:32.26%</text>
        </g>

    </g>

</svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works - you're just forgetting to adjust for your transform. So x+width has to be less than (viewbox width - transform x)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Based on this, I used `getBoundingClientRect()` instead of `getBBox()` as in the prod svg/html, the parent element might have multiple transformations and I can avoid accounting for the effect of each of them individually in the equation by using `getBoundingClientRect()` as it provides the `rendered` coordinate in my understanding. Hence, I used `getBoundingClientRect()`. However, I think it is still not working cause the DOM coordinate has not been correctly translated to svg coordinate.

Comment: The issue (I think at least) is that the SVG viewBox is being scaled to the available width via your meta-tag so viewBox units are no longer equal to CSS pixels - which is what getB...Rect returns.

Comment: Awesome !!!! just by doing this, `<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->` did what I expected it to do. Are there any side effects of it I should be aware of before putting this in prod?. Thanks for sharing this. This is simply mind-blowing.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the text-anchor attribute to "end" all the texts will align to the right. Would that be OK?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
  <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="black" stroke="bound"/>
  <rect class="boundRect" x="70" y="70" width="1120" height="600" fill="black"/>
  <g class="bound" transform="translate(70 70)">
    <g class="lines">
      <path class="Cuba" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,385.8783581344254L46.666666666666664,340.04110795732606L93.33333333333333,340.04110795732606L140,340.04110795732606L186.66666666666666,340.04110795732606L233.33333333333334,340.04110795732606L280,261.5473775717186L326.6666666666667,261.5473775717186L373.3333333333333,261.5473775717186L420,261.5473775717186L466.6666666666667,261.5473775717186L513.3333333333333,193.79191415980043L560,193.79191415980043L606.6666666666666,193.79191415980043L653.3333333333334,174.38265408552468L700,174.38265408552468L746.6666666666666,140.17685505574866L793.3333333333334,140.17685505574866L840,140.17685505574866L886.6666666666666,140.17685505574866L933.3333333333334,140.17685505574866L980,99.07632474477359L1026.6666666666665,99.07632474477359L1073.3333333333335,99.07632474477359L1120,97.28970086328088"></path>
      <path class="Nicaragua" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,498.798228969007L46.666666666666664,498.798228969007L93.33333333333333,508.9184060721062L140,508.9184060721062M233.33333333333334,405.6265984654729L280,405.6265984654729L326.6666666666667,405.6265984654729L373.3333333333333,405.6265984654729L420,456.7774936061383L466.6666666666667,426.0869565217393L513.3333333333333,426.0869565217393L560,405.6265984654729L606.6666666666666,405.6265984654729L653.3333333333334,221.48337595907955L700,221.48337595907955L746.6666666666666,221.48337595907955L793.3333333333334,201.02301790281317L840,211.25319693094582L886.6666666666666,170.33248081841413L933.3333333333334,170.33248081841413L980,170.33248081841413L1026.6666666666665,180.56265984654772L1073.3333333333335,155.26826115061547L1120,124.24046541693643"></path>
            <path class="Chad" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,577.4117647058824L46.666666666666664,577.4117647058824L93.33333333333333,577.4117647058824L140,577.4117647058824L186.66666666666666,577.4117647058824M280,545.3510436432637L326.6666666666667,539.2789373814043L373.3333333333333,539.2789373814043L420,539.2789373814043L466.6666666666667,551.4231499051233L513.3333333333333,551.4231499051233L560,551.4231499051233L606.6666666666666,551.4231499051233L653.3333333333334,479.8498122653327L700,459.8247809762202L746.6666666666666,459.8247809762202L793.3333333333334,459.8247809762202L840,459.8247809762202L886.6666666666666,459.8247809762202L933.3333333333334,479.8498122653327L980,456.43070787637083L1026.6666666666665,459.94397759103623L1073.3333333333335,454.75671750181556L1120,296.39468690702114"></path>
            <path class="Rwanda" fill="none" stroke="white" opacity="1" d="M0,438.6554621848753L46.666666666666664,438.6554621848753L93.33333333333333,438.6554621848753L140,357.98319327731105L186.66666666666666,358.34658187599433L233.33333333333334,358.34658187599433L280,141.17647058823525L326.6666666666667,141.17647058823525L373.3333333333333,141.17647058823525L420,141.17647058823525L466.6666666666667,141.17647058823525L513.3333333333333,70.5882352941176L560,70.5882352941176L606.6666666666666,70.5882352941176L653.3333333333334,70.5882352941176L700,70.5882352941176L746.6666666666666,0L793.3333333333334,0L840,0L886.6666666666666,0L933.3333333333334,23.5294117647058L980,23.5294117647058L1026.6666666666665,23.5294117647058L1073.3333333333335,23.5294117647058L1120,23.5294117647058"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="Label" style="opacity: 1;">
      <text class="labelRwanda" text-anchor="end" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="23.5294117647058" style="overflow: visible;">Rwanda:61.25%</text>
      <text class="labelCuba" text-anchor="end" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="97.28970086328088" style="overflow: visible;">Cuba:53.41%</text>
      <text class="labelNicaragua" text-anchor="end" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="124.24046541693643" style="overflow: visible;">Nicaragua:50.55%</text>
      <text class="labelChad" text-anchor="end" fill="white" alignment-baseline="middle" x="1120" y="296.39468690702114" style="overflow: visible;">Chad:32.26%</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

A modern (standard) Web Component `<svg-linegraph>` can help.

To make data entry as easy as possible, we'll do them in HTML

```
<svg-linegraph>
  <path d="mx y....">Cuba</path>
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="3" d="mx y....">Nicaragua</path>
</svg-linegraph>
```

But this means the `<path>` Elements are now technically an `UnknownHTMLElement`, and not an SVG path.
This is easily fixed by reading all of these `<path>` and *adding* the **outerHTML** to an **existing** `<svg>` (that will add the paths in the correct SVG NameSpace)

While parsing all `<path>` we can set the user defined attributes or defaults.

We are still lazy... Those `<path>` can be in any sized `viewPort`.
So in one more step we parse the, now valid SVG!!, paths again, get the boundaries of each path, and thus *automagically* calculate the correct `viewPort`

Positioning the country label is easy, we get the **last** point in each `<path>` and position a `<text>` on the correct X,Y location. (and gave the viewPort an extra 100 units to draw the labels right of the chart)

All code required to create a `<svg-linegraph>` Web Component is:

Note: I simplified your original `d-path` values with: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor
You can, ofcourse, use any valid d-path

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-linegraph", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // ensure <svg-linegraph> innerHTML is parsed
        this.innerHTML = `<svg style="background:grey">${
          [...this.querySelectorAll("path")].map(path => {
              const cloneAttribute= (x,v)=> path.setAttribute(x, path.getAttribute(x)||v);
              cloneAttribute("fill", "none"); // prefer user defined settings
              cloneAttribute("stroke", "black");
              cloneAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
              return path.outerHTML;
          }).join("")}<g>COUNTRYLABELS GO HERE</g></svg>`;
        let xaxis=[], yaxis=[]; // find viewPort boundaries
        this.querySelector("g").innerHTML = [...this.querySelectorAll("path")].map(path => {
          let {x:labelX,y:labelY} = path.getPointAtLength(path.getTotalLength()); // last path point
          let {x,y,width,height} = path.getBBox();
          xaxis.push(x,x+width); yaxis.push(y,y+height);
          return `<text fill="red" stroke="black" font-family="Arial" font-size="20px" alignment-baseline="middle"
                        x="${labelX+5}" y="${labelY}">${path.innerHTML}</text>`;
        }).join("");
        xaxis.sort((a,b)=>a-b); yaxis.sort((a,b)=>a-b); // sort by number!
        let viewbox = `${xaxis.at(0)} ${yaxis.at(0)-10} ${xaxis.at(-1)+100} ${yaxis.at(-1)}`;
        this.querySelector("svg").setAttribute("viewBox",viewbox);
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<svg-linegraph>
  <path d="m0 386 47-46 46 0 47 0 47 0 46 0 47-78 47 0 46 0 47 0 47 0 46-68 47 0 47 0 46-20 47 0 47-34 46 0 47 0 47 0 46 0 47-41 47 0 46 0 47-2">Cuba</path>
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="3" d="m0 499 47 0 46 10 47 0m93-103 47 0 47 0 46 0 47 51 47-31 46 0 47-20 47 0 46-185 47 0 47 0 46-20 47 10 47-41 46 0 47 0 47 11 46-26 47-31">Nicaragua</path>
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="4" d="m0 577 47 0 46 0 47 0 47 0m93-32 47-6 46 0 47 0 47 12 46 0 47 0 47 0 46-71 47-20 47 0 46 0 47 0 47 0 46 20 47-24 47 4 46-5 47-159">Chad</path>
  <path d="m0 439 47 0 46 0 47-81 47 0 46 0 47-217 47 0 46 0 47 0 47 0 46-70 47 0 47 0 46 0 47 0 47-71 46 0 47 0 47 0 46 24 47 0 47 0 46 0 47 0">Rwanda</path>
</svg-linegraph>
```